# How to change Format to array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting some value in this format

```
 [["first"],["second"],["third"]]
```

and i want to get

```
 {"first","second","third"}
```

what should i do in javascript?

Comment: What you want to get is not a valid object in Javascript.

Comment: You can't have an object with only keys

Comment: Maybe like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/J33ye/

Comment: Do you mean `['first','second','third']` as your target?

Comment: yes smokeyphp i want this thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is illegal: `{"first","second","third"}`

An object must be a mapping of key-value pairs. The best you can achieve is this:

```
{`first`: null, `second`: null, `third`: null}
```

---

<kbd>[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/ey8QH/)</kbd>

```
var arr2d = [["first"], ["second"], ["third"]];
var arrFlat = arr2d.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
});

var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arrFlat.length; i++) {
    obj[arrFlat[i]] = null;
}

console.log(obj);
```